How can I fix this NUnit testing issue?
I have test data and test like this below:
 private static TestDataClass[] _data =
 [
     new() {Id = 10, ..},
     new() {Id = 20, .. },
     ...
     new() {Id = 170, .. }
 ]

 [Test]
 [NonParallelizable]
 public void Should_Test([ValueSource(nameof(_data))] TestDataClass data)
 {
     //call method under test

     switch (data.Id)
     {
         case(10):
            // assertions

         ...
         case(170):
            // assertions
     }
 }

Some cases are failing when the tests are done together. Failed tests run fine when I run 1 case at a time from the unit test session. It seemed to me, by de-bugging that there is race condition and so I applied [NonParallelizable] attribute but it did not fix the issue.
